# Asking help for understanding OOP and inheritance in VB

Tags: vb.net, oop, inheritance

I am making a WinForms aplication where I have a graphic interface with textboxes and comboboxes where the user can input information about vehicles such as brand or color. It has two radiobuttons to choose if the vehicle is either a car or a motorcycle. It only has two buttons, one called "create vehicle" and another one "show info" which displays in a textbox all the data the user has input.

Then I have the classes `Form1`, `Vehicle`, `Car`, and `Motorcicle` (both inherit from `Vehicle`).

In classes `vehicle`, `car`, and `motorcicle`, I have all the attributes, an empty constructor and one with parameters, and also a method that should show the info provided for each vehicle.

The thing is, I don't know **where and how** I should instance `Vehicle` or the other classes, and if I need to assign the attributes from each class a value from the form. How and where do I call the method?

I imagine all of this should be done in `Form1`, but again, do I call it from the sub that handles the create button?

Comment: Yes your button should probably initiate the creation of a vehicle, specifically either a car or bike, depending on your radio button. Your OOP stuff is simple, but looks ok. The important thing to remember is that your form doesn't hold your state; you should have object instances behind. So if this is a single form app, then it's acceptable to have a private property `List(Of Vehicle)` to hold your instances, which you add to (`.Add(New Car() With {.Property1 = Value1, .Property2 = Value2})` for example) in the button.

Comment: If your instances are modified from outside of the form (or even inside for that matter), you can create Events which the form subscribes to. The instance should not modify the form directly. This is the best way for information to flow between your UI and data: UI changes >> Data via properties, Data changes >> UI via events. You can add Events to your Vehicle class, and raise them when changing properties, and subscribe in your form when vehicles are created.

Comment: Sorry, though. Your question is quite broad. An answer would be too big for this platform. You can however add code of your classes and button event handlers and ask a more specific question, and we'll be more than happy to help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably mark your `vehicle` class as `MustInherit` (`abstract` in c#) - meaning a class that can only be used as a base class for other classes, and can't be directly instantiated (except from it's derived classes).

In the **Create vehicle** button click event handler you should create either an instance of the `Car` or the `Motorcycle` class, but in the **Show info** button click event handler you should reference the `vehicle` class - assuming, of course, it has a `MustInherit` method called `GetInfo`.
This method should return a string, and be overrided in the derived classes.
Then, once you get the info in the event handler, you should display in on the form.

Basically, something like this should get you started:

```
Public MustInherit Class Vehicle
    ' this method should only return the info,
    ' it's the calling method that should decide what to do with that info
    Public MustOverride Function GetInfo() As String
End Class

Public Class Car
    Inherits Vehicle

    ' return the car's specific info
    Public Overrides Function GetInfo() As String
    End Function
End Class

Public Class Motorcycle
    Inherits Vehicle

    ' return the motorcycle's specific info
    Public Overrides Function GetInfo() As String
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Glad to help :-)